# Testing restricted permissions in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator

Various authorization statuse enums in the iOS SDK have a "Restricted" value, which is for when the permission is globally restricted and the user cannot easily change it. I want to test the behavior of an app when the permissions are restricted.

Usually clearing the simulator with "Reset Content and Settings" is the best way to test the permission dialogs, but the simulator does not show a setting to set restrictions.

This is what I see on an iPhone, and it is missing from the simulator:

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Workaround? Yes, test on the device you show in the screenshot.

Comment: Testing permissions on a real device requires erasing it and setting it up again... looking for something more reasonable.

Comment: Why do you need to erase the device? At least for the regular privacy settings you can simply reset the privacy settings in the Settings app.

Comment: This is unbelievable, that Apple does not supply a decent emulator on which one can test the critical features.